# Disable auto persist Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

```
$client = $repository->find(1);
$client->setName($name);

$em->flush();
```

In the code above, when executing the "flush", the name change is sent to the database.

I imagine that this makes life easier for some developers, but in my case it has become a problem. I would like to disable this operation and have the changes made only when I manually run "$em->persist($client)"

Is there a way to do this globally instead of always using "$em->detach($client)"?

Comment: The easiest approach would be to use something besides Doctrine.  What you described is baked into Doctrine.  The second approach would be to reexamine why you want to change entities without the changes being persisted.  Once you have a clear understanding on why you wish to do this then you will probably see it is not the best idea.

Comment: Simply clone your entity that after fetch. `$client = $repository->find(1); $clientClone = clone $client;`

Comment: "simply clone" brings a lot of complexity, don't recommend it at all (clone does not do a deep copy, there might be issues with ids references etc), so it's is really tough to handle, been there.

Comment: You should specify why you do edit data on entity. As example, if you do it to enhanced views, you can create a View/Client object which is created with a Entity/Client argument. But like @LBA, I recommand to avoid a simply clone.